# Can I show custom Confirm dialog before some operation

Tags: jquery

I am using `ASP.NET/C#`.In one of my page I have a requirement where before `inserting data` into `database` I need to check if the `ApplicationNo` is unqiue.If it is not unique I need to show a `confirm dialog` which will inform the user that the `ApplicationNo` is not unique.Can I use custom `confirm dialog` for this purpose.
Thanks.

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange I did not know that I can make ajax call to check application no , so I was just looking for a starting point.I have not tried anything so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably use ajax for this and process your page accordingly after you receive your data from the ajax call.

```
 $.get(url,function(data){
    // once url data is fetched, use the data variable to get the response of the page content

    if (data == 'ApplicationNo') { 
       // your code to open confirm window

    }
    else {  }

 });
```

Comment: Thanks ,Can you point me to some links or something.I have not used Ajax before.Thanks.

Comment: But I am trying to insert data using Asp.Net Button.

Comment: No worries,what I am trying to do is when a user tries to insert data I need to check if ApplicationNo already exists if it does then I need to show a popup saying , appno already exists , do you want to continue.If yes button is pressed then insert duplicate appno , if no then do not proceed.

Comment: this example is missing a critical argument... data sent to server